# Get a value from form on submit - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am simply trying to achieve a simple form, whereby a User enters a value and clicks Submit.The number is then written onto the page between the P tags.

I am trying to avoid using *".this"* as the form will become more complex.

I can't quite work out why this doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

```
<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="form">
    Number <input type="text" name="number" class="number">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
</div>    
<p></p>    

<script>
  $(document).ready.$(".submit").click(function() {
      var number = $(".number").val();
      $(p).after("numberis :" + number);
  })
</script>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: i can work out a couple of reasons why this doesnt work: A) this is completely invalid syntax.

Comment: The html structure. Javascript syntax all are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use correct html structure and valid JavaScript syntax as below.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
       <title></title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript">        
            $(document).ready(function () {    
                $(".submit").click(function () {    
                    var number = $(".number").val();                    
                    $("p").text("number is :" + number);                    
                });
            });            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="post">
          <div id="form">
              Number
              <input type="text" name="number" class="number" />
              <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" />
          </div>
          <p></p>
        </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use "submit" as the trigger instead of "click" on the submit button in most cases:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    $('p').html($('.number').val());
    return false;
});
```

This will replace all `p`aragraphs' text with the number.

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theredhead/3ubn3mxm/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need to do , your code is not valid

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){       
     $("#submit").click(function(){
        var number= $( ".number" ).val();      
        $('p').html(number); 
     });     
   })    
</script>

<form id="form">
    Number <input type="text" name="number" class="number">
    <input type="button" id='submit' name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>
<p></p>
```